# SendGrid api email activity response authorization required

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a sendgrid account which includes 7 days of email history.
I try to get these with the api command:

`var sendgridtask = sendgridclient.RequestAsync(method: SendGrid.SendGridClient.Method.GET, urlPath: "messages?limit=10");`

but this gives the response:
`{"errors":[{"message":"authorization required"}]}`

I guess the api key isn't correct, but when I try to execute the command:

`var sendgridtask = sendgridclient.RequestAsync(method: SendGrid.SendGridClient.Method.GET, urlPath: "suppression/bounces/" + email);`

it gives no error and responses the right info.
I checked the api key and it has full access.

I've also tried:
`sendgridclient.AddAuthorization(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}"));`

but this gives the same response

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Already got an answer from SendGrid:

> Unfortunately in order to gain access to the Email Activity Feed API, you must purchase additional email activity history.
>
> Or you can use our event webhook for your activity. https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/

So it seems that our license included history is only accessible from the SendGrid website, not from the API without an additional license.

Comment: I just purchased the additional license to gain access to the Email Activity Feed API, created a new API key with Full Access enabled, and I am still getting the same "authorization required" message back. It's been less than 30 min, but still...

Comment: Worked for me after 1 hour since I purchased the add-on.

Comment: Yep, the same to me: purchased the addon, no access after 10-15 minutes.